# How to design fail over for Java application which is reading emails from Gmail Server

Tags: java, architecture

I am working on the Java-based application which reads the email from the Gmail server and store in the database for further processing.

Following is the steps I am doing to get emails.

1. I have one email id as 'testemail@gmail.com
2. Using java email API code I read all the emails and store into DB, later on, these emails go for an evaluation.
3. Reading email code is running on the one server only

I deployed this codebase on the second server but both the server is reading the same emails and storing in DB, due to this I have duplicate emails in the database. **I wanted to avoid this scenario and at the same time, I need a failover for reading emails because if one server goes down then I have the second server to read emails from the Gmail server.**

Comment: What if the database server goes down? Then the failover won't help.

Comment: @Kayaman: What about solving one issue after the other? And who told you that they are not using RAC?

Answer (score -1):

At a first step, you have to establish a mechanism that blocks one server from accessing the GMail INBOX while the other one is reading emails. You can use an entry in database table for that, or a file on a shared folder, or Zookeeper or whatever.

The IMAP protocol (nor the POP3 protocol) does not know something like "record locking", not even a locking on higher levels, so no support from that side. You cannot even get an information how many clients are currently connected to a given mail box (at least not with the IMAP or POP3 protocols, and I am not aware of a Google API that would tell you that for a GMail account).

Next you mark the processed emails as read in the INBOX (and subsequent read attempts will ignore already read emails). Or you will move processed emails to a dedicated IMAP folder on the mail box.

If you just want to have a fail-over (the other server is cold), you will have to sort this out on the server level; this is again not related to the mail box access.